# How to define a function that takes input from user and stores that to a variable which is further used in the program?

Tags: c, function, cs50

I am writing this following code, but when I give an input and try to execute, the result is always according to the FALSE case even if the condition for true justifies.
Eg: If I put h=2, it follows a false case and if I put h=34 then also it follows a false case.
Kindly tell me the mistake that I am making.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int input(int a);
void pyramid(void);
int h;
int main(void) {
  input(h);
  if(h>0 && h<9) {
       pyramid();
    }
  else {
       do {
          input(h);
       } while(h>8 || h<1);
       pyramid();
  }
}

void pyramid(void) {
  printf("sfsdfsf");
}   

int input(int a) {
  printf("Height: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  return(a);
}
```

Comment: `input` returns a value, but the caller never uses it. `input` takes its parameter by value; changes made to it are not visible to the caller.

Comment: Kindly elaborate

Comment: Which part do you find unclear?

Comment: I called the function and then checked for the condition, but the function always returns '0' and not the input I typed.

Comment: How do you know what the function returns, when you discard and never use its return value?

Comment: okay @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Why does `input` need a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you call `input`: `input(h);`. `h` is passed by value (or by copy), which means that whatever happens in the function nothing will be visible to `h`. Thus:

Either you use the return value of the function:

```
h = input(h);
```

In that case, passing a value to the function is somehow strange...
So a prefered trick could be:

```
h = input();

int input() {
  int a;
  printf("Height: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  return a;
}
```

this express more clearly the fact that you call a function that makes something to return you a value (what this function really does is not interesting at the call point).

Either you pass the address of the variable:

```
input(&h);

void input(int *a) {
  printf("Height: ");
  scanf("%d", a);
}
```

That expresses the fact that the function takes the address of a variable that it will modify.

Suppose you want to get the phone number of a friend onto a paper, there is two solutions:

1. let him write it onto a paper he owns and gave you the paper in return.
2. let him write it onto a paper you gave to him.

Comment: What about the return value from `scanf`

Comment: I got it. Thanks, Jean